# jQuery toggle (hide/show) children class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started using jQuery, and I am stuck at toggle for children in below scenario:

```
<div id="id1">
  <heade>
    <div class="hideshow1"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow2"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="id2">
  <header>
    <div class="hideshow1"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow2"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I am trying to do here is hide all `class="hideshow1"` and `class="hideshow2"` but not `h2` when initial page load.
But when user hover the pointer over any part of `id="id1"` then only display `class="hideshow1"` and `class="hideshow2"` inside respective div and hide when remove pointer.

If any jQuery expert can share some info.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS for that?

Comment: add js fiddle with jquery function

Comment: `<header>` not `<heade>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the wrapping element is hovered, if so display its children or alternatively hide its children elements.

Ref: [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Code:

```
$("#id1, #id2").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".hideshow1, .hideshow2").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".hideshow1, .hideshow2").hide();
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/53PgZ/

Answer (score 0):

You should juste have 1 class, which is "hideshow", and let it be display: none by default. Then, on mouseover, display it for the current element. Also, you can bind element on one class. Something like this:

```
<div class="trigger">
  <heade>
    <div class="hideshow"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="trigger">
  <header>
    <div class="hideshow"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>
```

Then:

```
$('.trigger').on('mouseover', function(e) { $(this).children('hideshow').show(); }).on('mouseout',function(e) { $(this).children('hideshow').hide() });
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div id="id1">
  <header>
    <div class="hideshow1"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow2"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="id2">
  <header>
    <div class="hideshow1"> Toggle this div </div>
    <div class="hideshow2"> Toggle this div </div>
    <h2> My Header </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="body1">
     This is my body 
   </div>
 </div>
```

**js**

```
$(".hideshow1").hide();
$(".hideshow2").hide();


$('#id1').hover(
    function () {
         $(".hideshow1").show();
         $(".hideshow2").show();           
    },
    function () {
        $(".hideshow1").hide();
        $(".hideshow2").hide();           
    }
);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/795u9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#id1, #id2').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.hideshow1, .hideshow2', this).toggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Z7a/

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution with CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/8rk88/):

```
.container .hideshow1, .container .hideshow2 {
    display: none;
}
.container:hover .hideshow1, .container:hover .hideshow2 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest *not* using jQuery (or JavaScript at all) for this, and to instead use CSS:

```
div.hideshow1,
div.hideshow2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover div.hideshow1,
div:hover div.hideshow2 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3xEqq/).

You could, of course, use `display` instead of `visibility`, but be aware that this means there will be some moderately unpleasant 'jumping' as the content appears/disappears ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3xEqq/2/)).

If you'd prefer a slightly more graceful fade-in/fade-out approach you could implement transitions:

```
div.hideshow1,
div.hideshow2 {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

div:hover div.hideshow1,
div:hover div.hideshow2 {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3xEqq/1/).